# Как подсчитать количество удаленных файлов из директории?

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система, glob

Использую такой код для удаления всех файлов и папок:

```py
for file in glob.glob('*.*'):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        os.remove(file)

for directory in glob.glob('*/'):
    if os.path.exists(directory):
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
```

Как можно подсчитать количество удаленных файлов из директории?

Чтобы вывод был примерно таким:

> Удалено 30 файлов из 70!

Comment: Допустим после 'If' можно к переменной (пусть a), и прибавлять к ней 1, при каждом удалении, и потом выводить a

Comment: Благодарю, можете дать какой-нибудь пример? :)

Comment: `можете дать какой-нибудь пример?` да пожалуйста, нате: `++a`.

Comment: для того, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос нужно понимать по какому критерию вы кдаляете файлы/директории и будут ли у вас вложенные директории, которые нужно удалять... Лучше всего привести в вопросе пример структуры директории в текстовом виде и пояснить что вы хотите удалить, а что нет

Comment: удаляю все файлы, файлы из директории также. Однако, делаю исключение на не удаляемые файлы. С прошлым примером получилось вывести по одной цифре на каждый файл (1.. 1. 1.. 1), как я могу сложить все получившиеся значения в одно целое?

Comment: `сложить все получившиеся значения в одно цело`, вы действительно такой трудный или мой пример не понимаете? определяем счетчик  `a = 0` при удалении `++a` выводим `print(a)`. И если удаляете все, то лучше гляньте на второй параметр функции `glob`

Comment: @And `a += 1`, Python не умеет в `++` :(

Comment: @nomnoms12, тупой питон, точняк (забыл что числа не изменяемые у него), `a = a + 1` или да как вы и заметили `a += 1`

Comment: @And, это не связано с неизменяемостью чисел. В Python просто нет операторов `++` и `--`, хотя есть оператор `+=` и аналогичные.

Comment: @insolor, как-раз в данном случае это связано, так как само значение не умеет прибавляться или умножаться, только возводиться в степень, а когда делается так `a+=1` тут уже копирование происходит с последующим сложением и присвоением.

Comment: @And, точно так же мог и ++ работать - возвращать новый экземпляр объекта. Просто этого оператора в Python нет - "не завезли".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В том случае когда вы используете `shutil.rmtree(directory)` для удаления директории *со всеми поддиректориями*, единственное, что приходит на ум - это подсчитать число файлов **до** и **после** удаления:

```
my_dir = r"c:\temp"

files_before = sum([len(files) for root,dr,files in os.walk(my_dir)])
# deleting files here
files_after = sum([len(files) for root,dr,files in os.walk(my_dir)])
```